# Convert a String to Custom Type Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, tuples

Hello there I am trying to convert this String

```
Blade Runner,Ridley Scott,1982,Amy,5,Bill,8,Ian,7,Kevin,9,Emma,4,Sam,7,Megan,4​
```

To a Film Type

```
type UserRatings = (String,Int) 
type Film = (Title, Director, Year , [UserRatings])
```

from a text file that contains 25 films

this is what i tried to do

```
maybeReadTup :: String ->(String, Int)
maybeReadTup s = do
  [(n, [c])] <- return $ reads s
  return [(n, [c])]

    parseLines :: [String] -> Film
    parseLines list 
            |  isInt(list !! 3) = (list !! 0,(list !! 1), read (list !! 2), maybeReadTup [ (list!!1,read (list !! 2) )])

isInt :: String ->Bool
isInt[] = True
isInt (x:xs)
    | isNumber x = True && isInt xs
    | otherwise = False

parseChars :: String -> String -> [String]
parseChars [] _ = []
parseChars (x:xs) stringCount
    | x == ',' = [stringCount] ++ parseChars xs ""
    | otherwise = (parseChars xs (stringCount ++ [x]))

parseAll :: [String] -> [Film]
parseAll [] = []
parseAll (x:xs) = parseLines (parseChars x "") : (parseAll xs)
```

But i get wrong the types can someone please help me parse this UserRatings tuple type `[(String,Int)]` ? And can you help me understand how parseLines work? I'm new in Haskell

Comment: Why is every single word in the input separated by commas?

Comment: @chepner is there a better way to do this? If I change the file will it help me to parse it?

Comment: I would imagine something like `Blade Runner,Ridley Scott,1982,...` would be better, so that you know where the title ends and the director begins (assuming, of course, that titles don't *contain* commas).

Comment: @chepner you are right that is how i have it it is a typo mistake sry do you have any ideas of how can i do it?

Comment: if you want to keep `,` in your title/director you could change the separator to `;`

Comment: I am sorry guys that was a typo the separator is "," but still I have problem with the types

Comment: Btw there have been asked many haskell + film questions lately - use the search function it might be helpful

Comment: @epsilonhalbe any example would be appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhaskell%5D+film

Comment: @epsilonhalbe most of these i have seen already my question is purely about the reading from a text file correctly. it is different from all these other questions.

Comment: 1. please make your file compile or provide the error message you cannot understand, 2. Ask a meaningful question - "i get wrong types" is not nearly specific enough, 3. the indentation of `parseLines` is wrong, 4. you have not defined everything - Author, Title, Year are missing - I can guess them. But please show at least as much effort in posting a question as you expect somebody responding to you. A valid but totally unhelpful answer to your question "can somebody help me" would be "yes".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `Text.Parsec`:

```
import           Text.Parsec
import           Text.Parsec.String

type UserRatings = (String, Int)
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Film = (Title, Director, Year, [UserRatings])

str :: Parser String
str = many1 (noneOf ",")

int :: Parser Int
int = read <$> many1 digit

tup :: Parser UserRatings
tup = do user <- str
         _ <- oneOf ","
         rating <- int
         return (user, rating)

parser :: Parser Film
parser = do title <- str
            _ <- oneOf ","
            director <- str
            _ <- oneOf ","
            year <- int
            _ <- oneOf ","
            ratings <- sepBy tup (oneOf ",")
            eof
            return (title, director, year, ratings)

testString :: String
testString = "Blade Runner,Ridley Scott,1982,Amy,5,Bill,8,Ian,7,Kevin,9,Emma,4,Sam,7,Megan,4"

main :: IO ()
main = print $ runParser parser () "testString" testString
```

Comment: I have a database though so "testString" is useless for me how can i fix this code here to put my database in the parser?
`main :: IO ()
main = do 
    tempDatabase <- readFile "films.txt"
    let i = lines tempDatabase
    let database = runParser parser () database
    putStrLn "Enter your name: "
    username <- getLine
    userInterface database username
    appendFile "films.txt" (show database)
    putStrLn "Your changes to the database have been successfully saved."`

Comment: Calling a text file a database is a bit of a stretch.
`filmList <- map (runParser parser () fileName) <$> lines <$> readFile fileName` should work.